# URL encoding of "&"

Tags: java, android, url, encoding, httpconnection

I am currently facing an issue with sending some encoded characters. My main aim is to send the text using a POST https request. The catch is that the back-end is not quite the best one, so special letters (such as `æ`) I have to send in a special (custom) way.

Giving a simple example, I have the text `hjælp`. The letter `æ` should become `&aelig` in order the back-end to understand that it's this specific letter.

My url looks like this:

```
https://example.com/back-end/sendText?user=admin&text=hj&aeliglp
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work, because the back-end would see `3` parameter keys: `user`, `text` and `aeliglp`.

Of course, in code, my `url` is an actual `URL` object. However, if I use `URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8");` it would turn my `&` into `%26` and the `%26` itself to `%2526`.

On wikipedia I read about this:

> Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for
>   percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that
>   octet to be used as data within a URI.

Nevertheless, I *must* send it with a `%26`, but without encoding it to `%2526`. That is because I cannot change or ask for a change on the back-end.

In order to send the POST I use the most basic way:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //url is my URL object
conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
int result = conn.getResponseCode();
```

Is there any way I can create an `URL` object without encoding it automatically?

Comment: How are you encoding, are you encoding url parmaeters separately or the entire URL? `System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("hj&aeliglp", "UTF-8"));` gives me: `hj%26aeliglp` But I think server side, this will be just the same as if you sent '&'.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your problem: the javadoc for class URL says that it *does not itself encode or decode any URL components according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396*. So it seems you could use the URLEncoder and fixup the bad ampersand escape?